# Using OpenCV function in PyQGIS - Module not found

Tags: installation, ppygis, opencv

I would like to write a code using the OpenCV function `cv2.bitwise_and`, and run it in the Python console on QGIS. To do so, I start my code with `import cv2`. QGIS is returning the following error : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`.

To install OpenCV, I followed this tutorial: [How to install Python 3 and Opencv 4 on Windows](https://pysource.com/2019/03/15/how-to-install-python-3-and-opencv-4-on-windows/).

The version of Python I install is the 3.6.8, and for OpenCV it is the 4.2.0. When I use the cmd, I can see that OpenCV is correctly install (+ when I run `import cv2` in IDLE, it is working, and so is the function).

I have QGIS 3.10.2, and Windows 10. Does anyone knows what is wrong with my installation? Why can't I use OpenCV in QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably install OpenCV to different Python installation not installed by QGIS. Python 3.7 is already installed by QGIS. Therefore, to install 3rd party Python libraries for QGIS on Windows, you don't have but you should use OSGeo Shell.

- Open OSGeo Shell. (You may need to run as administrator. I was able to install in administrator mode)

  [image].
- Run `py3_env`.
- Check Python version using `python -V`.
- Download related `.whl` file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv).
- Then install OpenCV using `pip install C:\Users\user\Downloads\opencv_......whl`

  [image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Try to update `pip`. Go to `C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37` in OSGeo Shell, and run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Or check file path.

Comment: When I install OpenCV with the command line you gave me, I have this error message : Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\osgeo4~1\bin\python3.exe"  "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe" install C:\Users\Caroline\Downloads\opencv_python-4.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Navigate to `C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\Scripts` in OSGeo Shell, then run `pip install add_file_whl_path_here`.

Comment: Upgrade pip give "Requirement already up-to-date". I checked the file path, and it is correct...

Comment: Adding the path leads to this message : Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\osgeo4~1\bin\python3.exe"  "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe" install add C:\Users\Caroline\Downloads': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: In the OSGeo Shell, I change direction to the 'Downloads' folder, then type 'python -m pip install name_of_the_whl_file' and it works ! Thanks for your help and time !